# VSCode unable to import python libraries

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am using vscode and in the python environment setup, whenever i am able to run the script it is showing the import error.
the compiler is failed to import the libraries
[image]

Comment: That's just a statement. And what is your question? Do you want to replace the affected code by something else? Do you want to install the libs? Do you want to try jQuery instead?

Comment: i want to install the libs.. actually i already downloaded but its not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing your dependencies?
If it is just through local `pip`, then running `pip install` or `pip3 install` within the same directory as your `requirements.txt` file should work.

If you are using `poetry`, then it might get a little involved.
Again, if these are all local, first try running `poetry install` within the same directory as `pyproject.toml` file.

If you are using virtual environments with poetry, try:

1. Run the command `poetry shell` to get all of the values you need in order to update vscode's `preferences.json` file (to get to this file, open Code > Preferences > Settings and then click the document icon in the upper right corner)
2. When you see **"Spawning shell within...."** copy/paste that path into virtual environment path `"python.venvPath": "<Virtualenv.Path value>"`
3. While inside of the shell, type `which python` to get your second value, python path `"python.pythonPath": "<Virtualenv.Python value>"`
4. Last, click on the python version number in the status bar of your vscode window and make sure to set it to the value that's in step 3.